# Construct date sequence in Scala

Tags: scala, datetime, stream

I want to have a continuous date sequence like ['2014-01-01','2014-01-02', ...]

Then I define a stream to do that.

```
def daySeq(start: Date): Stream[Date] = Stream.cons(start,  daySeq(plusDays(start, 1)))
```

I get the sequence within range [start, end) by calling

```
daySeq(from).takeWhile(_.getTime < to.getTime)
```

Any better/simple solution to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using Joda-Time's `LocalDate` instead of Java's `Date` to represent dates without a time zone.

Assuming you only need to traverse the days once, use an `Iterator` instead of a `Stream`.

```
def dayIterator(start: LocalDate, end: LocalDate) = Iterator.iterate(start)(_ plusDays 1) takeWhile (_ isBefore end)
```

Example usage:

```
dayIterator(new LocalDate("2013-10-01"), new LocalDate("2014-01-30")).foreach(println)
```

If you do need a lazily-evaluated list, then `Stream` is appropriate. I suggest using `iterate` instead of `cons` in that case.

```
def dayStream(start: LocalDate, end: LocalDate) = Stream.iterate(start)(_ plusDays 1) takeWhile (_ isBefore end)
```

Comment: iterate looks better and simpler

Comment: FYI: The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), its creator, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), having gone on to lead [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) defining the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8+. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: This works with the java.time classes if you replace `new LocalDate` with `LocalDate.parse`

Answer (score 3):

> Any better/simple solution to do this ?

Yes. Functionality now built into Java 9 and later.

## `java.time.LocalDate::datesUntil` ➙ Stream of `LocalDate` objects

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

The `java.time.LocalDate` has built-in support for generating a stream of dates. Call [`LocalDate::datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate)).

I do not know Scala, so here is Java syntax.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( ZoneId.of ( "Africa/Tunis" ) );
LocalDate later = today.plusDays ( 3 );
List < LocalDate > dates = today.datesUntil ( later ).collect ( Collectors.toUnmodifiableList () );
```

> [2019-10-04, 2019-10-05, 2019-10-06]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: It's worth noting that the LocalDate::datesUntil method was one of the "minor features" added in Java 9. This means that it's not available if you're using an environment that is running on Java 8, which many things are since it's an LTS release.